# For any linear form there exists a unique vector $x_0$ s.t. $f(y) = (x_0 , y)$

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be any linear form. Show that there exists a unique $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $f(y)= (x_0,y)$  $, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. $(x,y)$ denotes the euclidian scalar product.

Proof:

Since $f$ is linear, we can represent it as a matrix. $f(y) = y^TM$. Where $M$ is the matrix representation of the linear application.
Now choose $x_0 = (y^TMy^{-1})^T \implies (x_0,y)=x_0^Ty=((y^TMy^{-1})^T)^Ty=y^TM = f(y).$

Now to prove $x_0$ is unique:

Suppose $\exists x_1$ s.t. $f(y) = (x_0, y)=(x_1,y) \implies x_0^Ty=x_1^Ty \implies x_0 = x_1$.

Is that a valid proof? Are there any other ways to prove this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to prove it: Let $\vec{e}_1=(1,0,0,...,0), \vec{e}_2=(0,1,0,...,0), \vec{e}_n=(0,0,0,...,1)$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
Suppose that 
$$f(\vec{e}_i)=c_i\mbox{ for }1\leq i\leq n.\tag{1}$$ 
Then we claim that 
$$f(\vec{y})=\langle \vec{c},\vec{y}\rangle\mbox{ for any }\vec{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n\tag{2}$$ 
where $\vec{c}$ is the vector given by $\vec{c}=(c_1,c_2,c_3,...,c_n)$.

To prove $(2)$, note that for any $\vec{y}=(y_1,y_2,y_3,...,y_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have 
$\vec{y}=y_1 \vec{e}_1+y_2 \vec{e}_2+\cdots y_n \vec{e}_n$. This gives 
$$f(\vec{y})=f(y_1 \vec{e}_1+y_2 \vec{e}_2+\cdots y_n \vec{e}_n)=
y_1 f(\vec{e}_1)+y_2 f(\vec{e}_2)+\cdots y_n f(\vec{e}_n)~~\mbox{ since $f$ is linear}\\
=y_1 c_1+y_2 c_2+\cdots y_n c_n~~\mbox{ by $(1)$}\\
=\langle \vec{c},\vec{y}\rangle.$$
This proves $(2)$.